# Extracting specific time points from two different time vectors in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I have two time vectors:

```
V1 = ['02-Feb-2018 08:23:42' '02-Feb-2018 08:24:42'.... '02-Feb-2018 09:10:42']
V2 = [' 8:35 AM' ' 8:36 AM'...' 9:01 AM'].
```

Now, I want to identify the indices of starting (`t0`) and ending point (`tend`) of `V2` (in this case `t0 = '8:35 AM'` and `tend = '9:01 AM'`) in `V1` and initialize a vector `V3` (of length `V1`) which contains `'1'` between `t0` and tend, and `'0'` in other time points. Since `v1` and `V2` are in different formats, i am not sure how to use `datestr` here. Below is the code which works if both `V2` is the same format as `V1`:

```
V1=['02-Feb-2018 08:23:42'; '02-Feb-2018 08:24:42';'02-Feb-2018 09:10:42'];
V2 = [' 8:35 AM' ;' 8:36 AM';' 9:01 AM'];
V1=datenum(V1);
V2=datenum(V2);
[~,t0]=min(abs(V2(1)-V1));
[~,tend]=min(abs(V2(end)-V1));
```

Comment: Are the timestamps of `V1` guaranteed to be on the same day?

Comment: Yes but it varies for different data. For example data 1 is on 02-feb and data 2 is on 03-feb and data 3 is on 10-feb and so on...

Comment: For example: In this case V1 is always on 02-Feb (belongs to data 1), For data 2, V1 is on 03-feb and V3 is on 10-feb and so on..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend utilizing [`datetime`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datetime.html) rather than [`datenum`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datenum.html) here. While `datenum` could be made to work, using `datetime` provides us with a much more helpful set of methods and allows us to more easily normalize the values of `V2` to the date of `V1`. One approach takes the dates from `V1` and assigns them to `V2`, which allows for direct logical comparisons using the start and end times.

For example:

```
V1 = ["02-Feb-2018 08:23:42"; "02-Feb-2018 08:24:42"; "02-Feb-2018 08:45:15"; "02-Feb-2018 09:10:42"];
V2 = ["8:35 AM"; "8:36 AM"; "9:01 AM"];

% Convert to datetime
d1 = datetime(V1);
d2 = datetime(V2, 'InputFormat', 'hh:mm a');  % Will assign today for date

% Assume all dates in V1 & V2 are the same
[y, m, d] = ymd(d1(1));  % Extract year, month, day from d1
[d2.Year, d2.Month, d2.Day] = deal(y, m, d);  % Set date of d2 to that of d1

% Find min/max of d2
t_0 = min(d2);
t_end = max(d2);

% Generate V3
V3 = zeros(size(V1));
V3((d1 >= t_0 & d1 <= t_end)) = 1;
```

Which returns:

```
>> V3.'

ans =

     0     0     1     0
```

As expected.

Note that I've added a timestamp to `V1` that falls within the time window generated by `V2`, which your original example doesn't have. I've also used arrays of [strings](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/create-string-arrays.html) (introduced in R2016b) to avoid having to whitespace pad a character array. If you're using an older version of MATLAB you should use a [cell array](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/cell-arrays.html) instead.